# MVC -- Differences between Models, Objects, and Repositories

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'd just like to get some clarification in the MVC pattern as to what belongs in Models, specifically the contents of the Models folder in MVC3, versus repositories and objects.

Right now, in my current MVC3 Solution, I have 4 projects:

1. A Project called "Objects", which holds information about all the core objects in my application.
2. A Project called "Data" which holds information information about the Data Context and repositories for each of the objects (created using MVC3 scaffolding)
3. The Web project, which holds the Controllers, Views, and -- the subject of this question -- Models
4. A Unit Testing project

What I really would like to get clarification about is the difference between what should go in the Objects project vs. what goes in the Models folder of the web project.  Right now I'm only using the Models folder for holding what I'd call "View Models", which typically contain combinations of the core objects.  Should the files in this folder only contain definitions defining the model contents, or should it contain other code that the controller may call?

I think that I have a pretty good understanding of both controllers and repositories, but sometimes I get confused as to whether certain code should go in one or the other.  Are there any specific guidelines or limitations out there as to what absolutely should NOT go in a controller but should go in either a repository or a model instead?

Thanks as always.

Comment: I personally put my viewmodels into ViewModels folder tree and models generated by Entity Framework into a Models folder tree.  I suspect others will have other approaches.  Conceptually, using EF I've gotten into the habit of having my controllers deal with the DB context and call `context.whatever.Add(myThing)` and call `context.SaveChanges()` - which might not be the "best" way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do something very similar except that the Objects and Data are combined in a Core library which is referenced by all projects. The models folder in the MVC project is strictly for View Models.

If your controller require additional classes, it really depends on what it needs as to where it goes. I will typically include a Helpers folder with subfolders for HtmlHelpers, Attributes and Filters. If it's a dependency that makes sense to exist outside the MVC project (common classes which are used across all projects) I'll add it to Core.